# get.php not comes in URL when we used media storage as Media Storage in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

We have used "database" under storage configuration for media section in magento.
All things and images save in database properly but they not comes in frontend with using this path.

We have not see get.php under image url for getting database media path. We have not understand what is exact problem with this.

We have used magento 1.9 version.

If we have run direct image path in browser then image showing properly.

Please let us know how we have find right path with get.php for all images path in our website.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this issue.

```
Please login your magento admin panel and go "System > Configuartion > Web > Search Engine Optimization" and select or check "** Use Web Server Rewrites**" value is "No".
```

After this please refresh cache at once.

Now Problem is solved.